# How to run this complex query on millions of rows

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have millions of rows of Message.rb

I have a migration I'm trying to run:

```
add_index :messages, [:mm_id, :c_id, :s_id], unique: true, name: :mm_unique
```

However the migration is failing because it is finding duplicate rows. I don't care what the value of s_id is (as long as it is an integer) and s_id and mm_id only need to be unique in the scope of c_id

So what I need to do is find all messages where mm_id IS NOT NULL and mm_id, s_id, and c_id have duplicate rows.

Then, how can I write a query to fix this quickly? I'd like to set a random value on s_id as long as it is an integer since i dont care what the value is.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be to find duplicate rows :

```
Message.joins("INNER JOIN 
               ( SELECT mm_id, s_id, c_id, COUNT(*) total_count
                 FROM messages GROUP BY mm_id, s_id, and c_id
                 HAVING  COUNT(*) >= 2
               ) b ON messages.mm_id = b.mm_id AND
                 messages.s_id = b.s_id AND messages.c_id = b.c_id"
             )
        .where("messages.mm_id IS NOT NULL")
        .select("messages.*, b.total_count AS duplicate")
```